# Exyjs4 field mapping issue

Tags: json, extjs4, mapping

I am working in extjs4 . I have json in format =

```
[
    {
        "id": 47,
        "review": null,
        "Versions": [
            {
                "id": 44,
                "version": 1,
                "Item": null,
                "file": {
                    "fileName": "File 98",
                    "title": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 47,
        "review": null,
        "Versions": [
            {
                "id": 45,
                "version": 1,
                "Item": null,
                "file": {
                    "fileName": "try.xls",
                    "title": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In model i want to access these fields. So i have written mapping as=

```
{name : 'versionId' , type : 'int' , mapping : 'Versions.version'},
{name : 'fileName' , type : 'string' , mapping : 'Versions.file.fileName'}
```

But its always showing versionId and fileName as blank. So how to do these mapping in extjs4

Comment: How are you loading the data? http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?142240-mapping-issues-with-Ext.data.Model-and-nested-JSON-Data-for-ExtJS-4-Grid-Store&p=633025&viewfull=1#post633025

Comment: I am loading data by using store proxy as= proxy : {
  type : 'ajax',
  actionMethods: {
         read: 'POST'
      },
  url: '/project.do',
  reader: {
   root: 'List',
   type: 'json',
   totalProperty: 'TotalRecords'
  },
  
 },

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a field type object in your model.

You will have to create a different store where root is Versions and map your fields from there...
I would also flat that file object inside Versions.